# Repeatable content in dynamic prototype UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I've got a problem where I have prototype cell with 6 labels on it and after that I have random number of views with picture on left side and text on right side as it is on [Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSJB4.png).

I tried to make a xib file which represents view with picture and label and constraints on it [Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fkaf.png).

Then I tried to make that view and add it with constraints to cell. It looks like constraints are totally wrong. This is how I tried to set constraints:

```
    for (index, entity) in linkedEntities.enumerate() {
            let linkedEntityView: LinkedEntityInExtendedSearchNotes = UIView.fromNib()
            linkedEntityView.entity = entity
            addSubview(linkedEntityView)
            linkedEntityView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            print(self.dynamicType)
            if index == 0 {
                let verticalSpace = NSLayoutConstraint(item: linkedEntityView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: noteTextLabel, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 8)
                let leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: linkedEntityView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .LeadingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 8)
                let trailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: linkedEntityView, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 8)
                NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([verticalSpace, leading, trailing])
            } else if index > 0 && index < linkedEntities.count - 1 {
                let verticalSpace = NSLayoutConstraint(item: linkedEntityView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: previousView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 8)
                let leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: linkedEntityView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 8)
                let trailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: linkedEntityView, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 8)
                NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([verticalSpace, leading, trailing])
            } else {
                let verticalSpace = NSLayoutConstraint(item: linkedEntityView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: previousView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 8)
                let leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: linkedEntityView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .LeadingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 8)
                let trailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: linkedEntityView, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 8 )
                let bottomSpace = NSLayoutConstraint(item: linkedEntityView, attribute: .BottomMargin, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 8)
                NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([verticalSpace, leading, trailing, bottomSpace])
            }

            previousView = linkedEntityView
        }
```

noteTextLabel is last label before repetitive content. Where I'm wrong with constraints? Is there any other (better) way to put repeatable content to prototype cell?

Thanks.